# What can I do to avoid blank laptop monitor after disconnecting external monitor?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, multi-monitor, laptop, lubuntu, lxqt

I'm using an old Lenovo X201 laptop with Lubuntu 2022, and more specifically, LXQt. When connected to an external monitor, I use the display settings dialog (or arandr) to enable the external monitor and disable the laptop monitor (so I can switch resolutions). But - I need to use the laptop monitor to do that, so the laptop has to be open. The situation is even worse when I do the opposite, since if I disconnected the external monitor - I now have to make this change *without seeing anything*.

I would like to do one of the following:

- Have a keyboard shortcut to switch the laptop monitor on.
- Get my desktop environment to recognize the situation of no monitor being both enabled internally and connected physically, and in that case, enable the laptop monitor.
- (sort of given up on this) recognizing the Fn+Monitor special keys on my X201.

Either of the first two would be nice; both abilities even nicer. Help?